# 'mbsc-datepicker' is not a known element: 1. If 'mbsc-datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, typescript

My program doesn't know Mbscmodule, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
code: 
<mbsc-datepicker [controls]="['calendar']" display="inline" [options]="calendarSettings"></mbsc-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install the Mobiscroll CLI and configure the app

```
$ npm install -g @mobiscroll/cli
```

Run mobiscroll config angular in your terminal window.

```
$ mobiscroll config angular
```

Step 2. Load the stylesheets

> Copy the code snippet with the CSS include and paste it to your index file. (This step may depend on your project's configuration. If your project has a specific css include location, then add the resource location there.)

```
<link href="/node_modules/@mobiscroll/angular/dist/css/mobiscroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Step 3. Import the mobiscroll module

> To import Mobiscroll, open app/app.module.ts and add the following
> statement after the other imports.

```
import { MbscModule } from '@mobiscroll/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

> Also add the MbscModule and the FormsModule to the imports enumeration

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   MbscModule,
   //... 
 ],
// ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MbscDatepickerOptions } from '@mobiscroll/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    myBirthday: Date;
    myOptions: MbscDatepickerOptions = {
        theme: 'ios',
        controls: ['calendar'],
    };
}
```

```html
<mbsc-datepicker [(ngModel)]="myBirthday" [options]="myOptions" placeholder="Please select..." />
```